# Perform Click on a Toolbar Button when I press Enter

Tags: .net, winforms

(ToolStripButton as Form's AcceptButton)

I have the following issue:

In my form I have a toolbar and want that by default the Enter press action be associated not with a standard *OK* button, but with an *OK* toolbar button (ToolStripButton).

In order to achieve this, I need to implement the `IButtonControl` interface, that I do in the following

Code:

```
public class MyTSB : System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton, IButtonControl
{
    public MyTSB()
        : base()
    {
    }

    DialogResult _DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
    public DialogResult DialogResult
    {
        get { return _DialogResult; }
        set { _DialogResult = value; }
    }

    bool isDefault = false;
    public void NotifyDefault(bool value)
    {
        this.isDefault = value;
    }

    protected virtual new void PerformClick()
    {
       // ???
    }

    void IButtonControl.PerformClick()
    {
        // ???
        this.OnClick(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

The issue is with `PerformClick` function. From one part, this function already exists in the ToolStripButton, from other, I never achieve to "Click" the (set as Form's acceptButton) toolstripButton...

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You could also overwrite the `ProcessCmdKey`-Method of the `Form` like this:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(
        ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg,
        System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
{
    switch (keyData) {
        case Keys.Return:
            this.yourToolStripButton.PerformClick();
            break;

        default:
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: your code works well (you just forgot 'ref' in the last function). However, I wonder about alternative implementation that I tried to do.